# Body bgcolor attribute weightage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written in css that body will have a blue color but in javascript i have made that body will change color every second, It worked until i added global css. I can't remove the css as it has many rules that i can't unlink. I want a way that all css rules will load but my body color won't get affected.

Screenshot to prove that body bgcolor has been changing by script but not shown:

http://i.gyazo.com/b6a7a0f4c5153c61b38c3552cdcd65fc.gif

Can someone show that how can i include that external global CSS but then also my script can change bgcolor and css will not stop it.

P.S : I am Noob :) !

EDIT:

My Code : http://fiddle.jshell.net/dfywom6a/

Help!

Comment: Show the code or make a fiddle, from images nothing we can tell :)

Comment: I think the javascript part is working fine. The problem must be at the css file. I guess the hierarchy is wrong. Post the code on fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code instead of document.bgColor to this document.body.style.background

Working example here http://fiddle.jshell.net/dfywom6a/42/

```
function cc() {
    window.setInterval("Farbe()", 500);
}
farbe = 1;

function Farbe() {
    if (farbe == 1) {
        document.body.style.background = "indigo";
        farbe = 2;
    } else if (farbe == 2) {
        document.body.style.background = "red";
        farbe = 3;
    } else if (farbe == 3) {
        document.body.style.background = "orange";
        farbe = 4;
    } else if (farbe == 4) {
        document.body.style.background = "blue";
        farbe = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use `document.body.style.background = color;` instead of `document.bgColor = color;`
That will override global css applied onto body element.

I hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/ceueqetn/

Answer (score 1):

The `bgColor` attribute is deprecated. So maybe the CSS rule overrides the color stated in the `bgColor` attribute.

So, instead of changing `bgColor` in your JavaScript, consider changing the CSS like this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.setProperty('background-color', 'red');
```

[Here is the updated version of your code.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dfywom6a/34/)

Answer (score 0):

try to add the `!important` on your color css.

```
body {
  background: #f00 !important;
}
```

Comment: That should be done in OP's **JS**, not in CSS, otherwise his frequent color-changes are overridden!

Comment: Have you tried this solution? It is cannot be overridden if the attribute has the important flag @MartinErnst

Comment: OP asked `how can i include that external global CSS but then also my script can change bgcolor`. That means: the JS must override the CSS.